# How to handle node modules Visual Studio 2017 Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I created a VS 2017 Angular 2 Project.  Then I did an NPM install of a package I wanted. It of course created the `node_modules` folder, which is not recognized when I run.

What is a clean way to use npm install with this type of project?

This is my project folder structure:

[image: Project Folder structure]

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"? We have webpack compile our files, and then we bundle them in C#.

Comment: I created project with VS 2017. Package.json is in root folder, so i run npm install from that folder. It creates a node_modules folder there. should i move package.json to wwwroot folder?  Also, some generated JS link is looking for a scripts folder, which does not exist.

Comment: Save yourself time/nerves and don't use anything but `angular cli` for angular projects.

Comment: @deezg The goal is try to integrate angular front end with ASP.NET WEB API backend. How would i do that if i go all angular cli route?

Comment: @WebBoy i know exactly what you mean. i had the same situation. what i ended up doing was having 2 completely separated projects: one visual studio project with web api and one separated anguler cli project that consumes web api. separate them completely. it is a few days (literally) to get used to it but in the long run you are far better of.